# Why is Calendar producing a date one month in the future

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to figure out how the Calendar class works. Why does the following code produces a date one month in the future:

```
package bondcalc;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import datefunctions.*;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
   cal.clear();
   cal.set(2012,9,20);
   Date d1 =cal.getTime();
   System.out.printf("Date1: %s%n",d1);      
}
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
Date1: Sat Oct 20 00:00:00 PDT 2012
```

Comment: months start at 0 - welcome to the date time libraries of java.....

Comment: Month seems to be counted from 0 here, so September is 8 and not 9

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you should use the constant values for the month. Use Calendar.SEPTEMBER instead

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Calendar` constants defined for months:

```
cal.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 20);
```

The month field of a `Calendar` is zero-based, like an array index.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH), Java months are 0-indexed. Thus, 9 here means October.

Answer (score 1):

The month field starts at index=0, so 0=January and 9=October.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
cal.set(2012,9,20);
```

to

```
cal.set(2012,8,20);
```

because the month field starts from zero according the [java Calendar doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)